# Use selenium on Ubuntu Server

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-server, geckodriver, headless-browser

I followed [this](http://scraping.pro/use-headless-firefox-scraping-linux/) tutorial to use selenium (headless firefox) on an ubuntu server.

All the installations seem fine, but when I try to run

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 7, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/root/environments/bib-session/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 162, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/root/environments/bib-session/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/root/environments/bib-session/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/root/environments/bib-session/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/root/environments/bib-session/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 255
```

With geckodriver.log:

```
1521816755947   geckodriver     INFO    geckodriver 0.20.0
1521816755953   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:50603
1521816756956   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.jsMhN1eu7Kun"
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox/libmozgtk.so:
libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

I have no clue how to fix this. Any help is welcome.

Comment: The tutorial is from 2014. 
Today you don't need to "Install Xvfb", because Firefox got "headless" option and it doesn't need Xvfb for that.
I haven't done it with Ubuntu, but here is my guide with CentOs:
https://github.com/SlavikCA/headless-tests/

Answer (score 0):

the output message included:
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox/libmozgtk.so:
libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.

that's mean you need to install package of libgtk-3. for FireFox

I also meet the same situation in the simple Debian Console-only environment. I do not install any X desktop/parts. After installation of libgtk-3 for Debian. Firefox could run in the xvfb virtual screen.

Comment: i saw the origin post you paste, that install libgtk-2. But the newer firefox use libgtk-3 to replace libgtk-2.

Comment: Hi surfer190, i saw your last reply. Do you mean to check the selenium webdriver version of 32bits/64bits ?

Comment: I mean the firefox version

Answer (score 0):

You installed the `linux-i686` version of firefox when you should have downloaded the 64 bit `linux-x86_64` version of firefox

Comment: Thank you. I just followed the tutorial. What would I need to change?